# Is there a way to use byte array on html5 source video tag

Tags: javascript, c#

I am getting a byte array from my mvc action method. I want to set it as source to HTMl video tag. How can it be done. My code is below.

```
var sourcePDF = '../../Content/Images/video.webm'
if (sourcePDF != undefined && sourcePDF.trim() != "") {
    var url = ResolvedUrl.replace('ActionName', 'StreamFile').replace('ControllerName', 'File');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify({ filename: sourcePDF }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: "JSON",
        success: function (response) {
            debugger; 
            console.log(response)
            var HealthCareIframeAppend = '<video  width="100%" height="inherit" src="' + response + '" autoplay controls ></video>';
            $('#HealthCareAttachementi').append(HealthCareIframeAppend);
            $('#_SwitchFullScreenContentNewTab').switchClass('show', 'hide');
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You would use a `data:` URI, however unless your video is only a few kilobytes (unlikely) then this would be a bad idea. Is there a reason you can't set the action to the `src=""` attribute of the `<video>` element?

Comment: My issue is that if i set the source in src, it is working fine for firefox but not in chrome becoz chrome has some compatibility issues with mp4 videos

Answer (score 1):

You can use base64 encoded string ant then place it inside your src tad, but it will be bad idea, because it will be huge. You can find demo at [here](https://iandevlin.com/html5/data-uri/video.php) (check source code of this page)

Tutorial how to do that you can find [here](https://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2012/09/html5/html5-media-and-data-uri).

But in your case, additional challenge is how to convert byte array to base64 string, that will consume time and memory, if you still want to do that, you can return base64 string from server

Comment: Converting a byte array to a base64 string is easy. The problem is that for a video file, that string will be massive, which will significantly reduce loading times, possibly to the point of unusability.

Comment: Sure, it is easy for small byte arrays, by "challenge" i mean for big arrays it might cause  performace issues and call stack size exceeded issues

Comment: so what is the solution. Is there any solution in C#?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this and it worked fine. It is working perfectly in Chrome and in firefox as well and you can also download the file in Chrome.
Here is my Javascript

```
var url= '../../Content/Images/video.webm'
var sourceVideo = parent.window.ResolvedUrl.replace('ActionName', 'videoStream').replace('ControllerName', 'File') + '?' + $.param({ "filePath": url });
 $('#HealthCareAttachementi video').remove();
 $('#HealthCareAttachementi iframe').remove();                       
 var HealthCareIframeAppend = '<video  width="100%" height="inherit"  autoplay controls >    <source src=' + sourceVideo + '    type="video/mp4" ></video>';                            $('#HealthCareAttachementi').append(HealthCareIframeAppend);
 $('#_SwitchFullScreenContentNewTab').switchClass('show', 'hide');
```

And here is the Action Method

```
       public void videoStream(string filePath)
    {
        //The header information 
        HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Training.mp4");

        var file = new FileInfo(filePath);
        //Check the file exist,  it will be written into the response 
        if (file.Exists)
        {
            var stream = file.OpenRead();
            var bytesinfile = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(bytesinfile, 0, (int)file.Length);
            HttpContext.Response.BinaryWrite(bytesinfile);
        }

    }
```